# iPad as a wireless webcam

Tags: webcam, ipad

Can I use my iPad as a wireless webcam for my PC? I think the solution would be an app streaming the video captured by the iPad's camera from the iPad to the PC where another app would decode it, emulating a local webcam like ManyCam does (ManyCam could very well be part of the solution to this problem). Kinda like Air Video but reversed. I haven't been able to figure out how to do it; has anyone else figured it out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about PocketCam?  It's only 5 dollars, and it does the job-even optimized for iPad.  Never used it before, but it sounds useful.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pocketcam/id316512204?mt=8